# Integrate with residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have this integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}dx$$

and i want to use residues to compute it, how do i do that when the limits are $0$ to $\infty$?

First of i define

$$f(z):= \frac{z^2}{(z^2+1)(z^2+4)} $$

I want do integrate this but over what contour? All the singularities are on the Im-axis so i can't chose the quarter circle in first quadrant, they have to be an inner point, correct? I have only dealt with integrals that goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and then i just take the points that are in the upper half circle, not sure what to do know tho...

Comment: The integrand is even, so $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}\,dx.$$ Can you now guess a useful contour?

Comment: Yes now i can solve it, thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to use advanced instruments when the problem is almost trivial?

By partial fraction decomposition,
$$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+4)}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{4}{z+4}-\frac{1}{z+1}\right),$$
hence your integral equals:
$$ \frac{1}{3}\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4}{x^2+4}\,dx-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{6}}.$$

Comment: I was going to post the same thing, but I decided against it. I can understand that one might want to show how to compute a simple problem using a complex method to help understand the fundamental workings of the complex solution.

Comment: The course is called "complex analysis", therefore I need to learn this :)

Comment: @Danny: but the fastest way to compute the residues of the integrand function at $i$ and $2i$ is exactly to perform a partial fraction decomposition, so why not to perform it as a first step?

Comment: That is a good point, I think i will do it both ways just to get the bigger picture. But doesn't that bring me back to the same question, what contours do i use?

Comment: @Danny: once you write the problem as finding an integral over $\mathbb{R}$ (by exploiting the parity of the integrand function), you may take just the usual contour, i.e. a big half-circle centered in the origin.

Comment: yeah but the integral isn't from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ ? So its not over the whole real axis?

Comment: @Danny: the original integral is not over the whole real axis, but an equivalent integral is (Daniel Fischer's comment).

Comment: Oh yeah I'm sorry, so you are rewriting it like that and then break it up. I think i get the hang of it now, thanks!